# Route Add to VMWare image "The route addtion failed: the parameter is incorrect"

Tags: routing, vmware-player

I have two physical PCs and one VMWare image on the LAN.  All are running Windows:

- PC1: 192.168.0.4
- PC2: 192.168.0.3
- VMWare image (NAT): 192.168.64.7

PROBLEM:

I'd like for PC1 to be able to communicate with the VMWare image running on PC2.

SYNTAX: On PC1:

`route -4 add 192.168.64.7 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.3 metric 2`

RESULT:

> The route addition failed: The parameter is incorrect.

Q: What exactly am I doing wrong?

Q: Is this even possible without taking the VMWare image's network adapter out of NAT mode and changing it to Bridged?

Thank you in advance .. PSM

Comment: bridged mode would be the super easy fix unless you have a reason not to have it on your local lan

Comment: Yup - bridged mode worked, and there's no down side with my particular LAN.  Thank you!